# SyntaxError: invalid syntax (Python 3.2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I have a function that will insert spaces in a tuple of strings so that all strings are equal in len. I also have a function that takes to tuples of strings and some formating info and combinde them to one tuple of strings

```
#code for equal string length
def insertSpace(self,content):
    max = 0
    for string in content:
        temp = len(string)
        if temp > max:
            max=temp
    retstring = ("",)
    for string in content: 
        retstring = retstring + ("&nbsp;"*(max - len(string)+1,)

    return self.combine(retstring,content,bold=False,newline=False)


#code for combine
def combine(self,leftside,rightside,bold=False,newline=False):

    if bold is True:
        bold = '<B>'
        boldend = '</B>'
    else:
        bold = ''
        boldend = ''

    if newline is True:
        newlinechar = '<br>'
    else:
        newlinechar = ''
    return tuple((bold +"{0}"+boldend+"{1}"+newlinechar).format(x,y) for x,y in zip(leftside,rightside))
```

and execution of this script results in this

```
File "mypythonfile.py", line 108
return self.combine(retstring,content,bold=False,newline=False)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried storing the value in a variable but that changed nothing. It is probaly something simple but I can't see it.

Comment: Found a bug in my code `retstring = ("",)` should be `retstring = ()`

Comment: You can edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a closing `)` on this line:

```
retstring = retstring + ("&nbsp;"*(max - len(string)+1,))
                                                        ^ 
                                                        |
```

**Edit:** In your code:

```
>>> 'retstring = retstring + ("&nbsp;"*(max - len(string)+1,)'.count("(")
3
>>> 'retstring = retstring + ("&nbsp;"*(max - len(string)+1,)'.count(")")
2
```

Comment: I was about to write my answer,but you are too Quick on Python :) .. So added in your answer

Comment: Thanks I know it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Ammend

```
retstring = retstring + ("&nbsp;"*(max - len(string)+1,)
```

To be

```
retstring = retstring + ("&nbsp;"*(max - len(string)+1,)) #note the closing bracket
```